Can neutrino decoupling time be pushed earlier?
In standard model cosmology, neutrinos decouple when the interaction rate was equal to Hubble expansion rate
$$T_{Dec} \approx (G_{F}^2 M_{pl})^{-1/3} \approx MeV$$
hence this occurs around 1 MeV approximately 1 second after the Big Bang with Fermi constant being $G_F \approx 10^{-5} GeV^{-2}$
Interaction rate
$$\Gamma_{\nu} \approx G_F^{2} T^5$$
And Hubble expansion rate
$$H \approx \frac{T^2}{M_{pl}}$$
Where $M_{pl} \approx 10^{19} GeV$
If one assumes neutrinos can have additional 4 Fermi-like interactions with a scalar field $\phi$ with a coupling strength of $G_{\nu} \approx g^2 / M_{\phi}^2$
There are 2 cases where one can compare the effective strength of new interactions with $G_F$
1) $G_{\nu} >> G_F$
In this case neutrino interaction rate would be dominated by new interactions hence this would yield to
$$T_{Dec} \approx (G_{\nu}^2 M_{pl})^{-1/3} << MeV$$
Hence this would lead to late decoupling time
2) $G_{\nu} << G_F$
In this case neutrino interaction rate would be dominated by standard model weak interactions hence this would give us back the decoupling temperature as before
$$T_{Dec} \approx (G_{F}^2 M_{pl})^{-1/3} \approx MeV$$

My question is while it's easy to delay the neutrino decoupling time by increasing the $G_{\nu}$, how could one take this time earlier?


A fun model-building question! Here are a couple directions along which you could explore writing a model beyond the Standard Model of particle physics and cosmology which would make neutrinos decouple earlier.

Introduce a new interaction which destructively interferes with the weak interaction. Unlike your scalar-mediated interaction, this should be introduced by a new vector so that it has the same Lorentz structure as the weak interactions. You must charge the neutrinos under a new gauge group which is spontaneously broken.

Raise the mass of the neutrinos in the early universe. This must be done by introducing additional scalars which at high temperatures have symmetry breaking vevs, but at low temperature transition to the unbroken phase. Maybe a second Higgs doublet $H'$ which gives large Dirac masses when it is condensed from $\mathcal{L} \supset \langle H' \rangle L N$. ($L$ is the lepton doublet and $N$ is a right-handed neutrino.)


Probably either of these toy models is very difficult/contrived to realize if there is any remaining parameter space for it at all.

For the first, you would have to think carefully about the flavor structure of the new interaction and whether you can really get enough interference. However, one also faces the problem that the SM left-handed neutrinos are in a doublet with the left-handed leptons. So one would have to explain why this new gauge interaction has not appeared in collider experiments involving electrons. There's a limit where the interaction is very weak where this must be allowed, but then maybe it doesn't interfere enough.

For the second, it's crucial that $H'$ no longer have a vev at low temperatures, as we know electroweak symmetry is broken mainly by the discovered $h(125)$ from electroweak precision observables. It would also be difficult to explain why there is no mixing between $h(125)$ and the radial mode of $H'$, though you could appeal to some fine-tuning. Also there will be constraints on interactions between electrons mediated by $H'$ and $N$ running in a loop which should put a lower limit on the mass of $H'$ today, but if this is much larger than the MeV scale then it becomes difficult to explain why $H'$ would uncondense so late.


In any case it's an interesting question, and one could perhaps come up with other strategies as well. I would be curious to hear of a realistic model that does this.

Thanks for the detailed answer, the possible cases you suggested are very interesting indeed and I would like to try if they can be realized but also they are very difficult as you pointed out. I was wondering if something simpler e.g. $G_{\nu}$ having a running behavior can push this time earlier.
